# shopping cart, possible to use Devise's session functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, e-commerce

I am writing an ecommerce website and I need to implement a shopping cart feature. I want the customers to be able to add products to their cart without signing up beforehand, so I figured I would accomplish this through sessions.

Can this be done in the Devise gem or will I have to implement my own session model for this to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to handle your own session data - doesn't mean you'll need a [session model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model) though.

We've implemented what you're looking for. It works using a session model, but uses the same base functionality I'd recommend for you:

```
#app/models/cart_session.rb
class CartSession

    #Initalize Cart Session
    def initialize(session)
        @session = session
        @session[:cart] ||= {}
    end

    #Cart Count
    def cart_count
        if (@session[:cart][:products] && @session[:cart][:products] != {})
            @session[:cart][:products].count
        else
            0
        end
    end

    #Cart Contents
    def cart_contents
        products = @session[:cart][:products]

        if (products && products != {})

            #Determine Quantities
            quantities = Hash[products.uniq.map {|i| [i, products.count(i)]}]

            #Get products from DB
            products_array = Product.find(products.uniq)

            #Create Qty Array
            products_new = {}
            products_array.each{
                |a| products_new[a] = {"qty" => quantities[a.id.to_s]}
            }

            #Output appended
            return products_new

        end

    end

    #Qty & Price Count
    def subtotal
        products = cart_contents

        #Get subtotal of the cart items
        subtotal = 0
        unless products.blank?
            products.each do |a|
                subtotal += (a[0]["price"].to_f * a[1]["qty"].to_f)
            end
        end

        return subtotal

    end

    #Build Hash For ActiveMerchant
    def build_order

        #Take cart objects & add them to items hash
        products = cart_contents

        @order = []
        products.each do |product|
            @order << {name: product[0].name, quantity: product[1]["qty"], amount: (product[0].price * 100).to_i }
        end

        return @order
    end

    #Build JSON Requests
    def build_json
        session = @session[:cart][:products]
        json = {:subtotal => self.subtotal.to_f.round(2), :qty => self.cart_count, :items => Hash[session.uniq.map {|i| [i, session.count(i)]}]}
        return json
    end

  
end
```

---

**Sessions**

According to the Rails [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark):

> Most applications need to keep track of certain state of a particular
> user. This could be the contents of a shopping basket or the user id
> of the currently logged in user. Without the idea of sessions, the
> user would have to identify, and probably authenticate, on every
> request. Rails will create a new session automatically if a new user
> accesses the application. It will load an existing session if the user
> has already used the application.

Sessions, to my knowledge, are small cookie files storing data for each user. These are ambiguous (are created for *every* user - regardless of whether they are signed in or not), which means I'd use them for your cart

We use `Sessions` to create cart data by storing raw `id`'s of the cart products in the session

---

**Devise**

A note on Devise - what you're asking about has nothing to do with the Devise gem. Devise is an authentication system, meaning it handles if a user has access to your app; it doesn't handle shopping cart data

Whilst Devise stores data in `sessions`, you'll need to define your own `session` data for your cart. We do this using a `cart` controller with the model code above:

```
#config/routes.rb
get 'cart' => 'cart#index', :as => 'cart_index'
post 'cart/add/:id' => 'cart#add', :as => 'cart_add'
delete 'cart/remove(/:id(/:all))' => 'cart#delete', :as => 'cart_delete'

#app/controllers/cart_controller.rb
class CartController < ApplicationController
    include ApplicationHelper

    #Index
    def index
        @items = cart_session.cart_contents
        @shipping = Shipping.all
    end

    #Add
    def add
        session[:cart] ||={}
        products = session[:cart][:products]

        #If exists, add new, else create new variable
        if (products && products != {})
            session[:cart][:products] << params[:id]
        else
            session[:cart][:products] = Array(params[:id])
        end

        #Handle the request
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: cart_session.build_json }
            format.html { redirect_to cart_index_path }
        end
    end

    #Delete
    def delete
        session[:cart] ||={}
        products = session[:cart][:products]
        id = params[:id]
        all = params[:all]

        #Is ID present?
        unless id.blank?
            unless all.blank?
                products.delete(params['id'])
            else
                products.delete_at(products.index(id) || products.length)
            end
        else
            products.delete
        end

        #Handle the request
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: cart_session.build_json }
            format.html { redirect_to cart_index_path }
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Lets say I am not adding to the cart from the index view (cart_index_path), but maybe a store view (store_path(:store_id))... how would I add a product to my cart but  keep the same view?  How would you pass in the :store_id?

Answer (score 0):

```
session[:product_id] = []
```

When user add some item to cart, push `id` of that item to this array

Comment: I see, but I will still need to implement some sort of session authentication system yeah?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
session["product_id"] << params["product_id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cart backed by database, you can keep cart id in session. Rails creates new session automatically when new user visit website. I have defined cart method in ApplicationController to manage cart.

```
def cart
    return Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        cart = Cart.create(:cart_count=> 0)
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    return cart
  end
```