# undefined local variable or method `cart_session' in cart controller ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopping-cart

I'm making an online book store using Ruby on Rails. Currently I'm stuck in the shopping cart feature, I've used the code posted by Rich Peck in an answer here
[shopping cart, possible to use Devise's session functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154206/shopping-cart-possible-to-use-devises-session-functionality)

However, I keep getting this error

NameError in CartController#index
undefined local variable or method `cart_session' for #

Extracted source (around line #6):
4
5
6
7
8
9

```
#Index
def index
    @items = cart_session.cart_contents
    @shipping = Shipping.all

end
```

I do have cart_session model that initialises a session 
class CartSession

```
#Initalize Cart Session
def initialize(session)
    @session = session
    @session[:cart] ||= {} 
end
```

How can I fix this error?

This is my first rails application so I also wanted to know if there is a simpler way to implement a shopping cart, like a gem or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us more informations about where you init your cart_session ?

Comment: I guess that could be `CartSession.cart_contents`.

Comment: @UgoMare The only part that handles initialising the session is in the cart_session model, the code of which is in the question.

Comment: @Pavan tried it, didn't work out.

Comment: But where cart_session is defined ?

Comment: I'm willing to be you've not defined a before filter to the application_controller which instantiates the cart on each call.