# Preserving Rails 4 Devise Session Id Before & After Sign In

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to implement an e-commerce app. In it, I allow the user to browse for products and put them into the cart even before signing in. I only prompt the user to sign in upon checkout.

However, I'm losing track of the user because the user's session id changes upon sign in. Due to this, Im unable to associate the items that the user placed into the cart (stored in redis) to the user who placed them in after the user signs in to the application.

Does anyone have any idea how could this be circumvented?

Thanks.

Cheers!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154206/shopping-cart-possible-to-use-devises-session-functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. All that needs to be done is set session.options[:renew] = false and the session id will still be the same before & after signing in.

Please refer to the implementation below

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    super
    session.options[:renew] = false
  end

  def destroy
    logger.info "Logging out: #{current_user.email}; Session Id: #{session.id}"
    $redis.del "cart_#{session.id}"
    super
  end

end
```

Comment: Just want to point out that this also circumvents the session fixation security that this feature provides.
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-fixation-countermeasures